# Is there a list of all online creative commons based journals?

Tags: peer-review, online-publication

I know there is a good list of all paper peer-reviewed journals but I would like to know is there one **specially** for creative commons based online journals? I am kind of trying to figure out which is better to publish in terms of access to "outsiders"-people who aren't research scientists and most likely will never care about research journals but if I post a link to my paper on a social media site would make the effort to see it. Is there anyone here who has experience with such audience? Publishing not for the colleagues, but for the general public. You know people these days don't like to pay to view something on the Internet and if your audience isn't a member of a faculty impact factor is crap. But I wish to know can my papers go through at least some kind of(even very rudimentary)peer-review process. This is why I am looking for a list of free online journals who have at least someone with academic background on their editorial board.

Does such a thing exists?

Comment: I would suggest writing a blog. You can ask some of your colleagues to read it in order to get "rudimentary peer review".  Your intended audience will be much more likely to read it.

Comment: I have tried writing in forums, social media, for sites for the general public, etc. but my feedback(at least in most cases)was that the site administrators(although they aren't scientists and often have no background in science)would much prefer to have to cite a peer-review paper in order to accept my text. It just helps a lot. I think the Internet is going in a direction where even a layman wants to see this text is based on some peer-reviewed work. And if you can provide a free-of-charge original peer-reviewed online paper he or she can read this adds credibility.

Comment: The point I make is in such cases the layman trusts the peer-review process itself, not the quality of the review. My experience is very few "common people" understand how peer-review works or even care for that matter. For them it is enough that you can say this journal has peer-review and this is science(see for example how those who oppose man-made climate change back up their claims with "scientific arguments"). This is why don't care what is its impact factor. What is important in the case is only to show it **is** a scientific journal. This is why ask about creative commons journals.

Comment: I hope you can "feel" the topic of my question. But if you have any suggestions how I can improve it, please, write them down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Directory of Open Access Journals ([DOAJ](http://doaj.org)) is "a community-curated online directory that indexes and provides access to high quality, open access, peer-reviewed journals."